# Determine the values of a for which the following linear system has

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Determine the values of $a$ for which the following linear system has (i) no
solutions, (ii) infinitely many solutions, (iii) exactly one solution:

\begin{cases}
x + 2y − 3z = 4 \\[4px]
3x − y + 5z = 2 \\[4px]
4x + y + (a^2 − 14)z = a + 2 
\end{cases}

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what tools you have available, it is difficult to give an answer as expected by your instructor. However, a standard procedure is Gaussian elimination on the system's matrix.
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & -3 & 4 \\
3 & -1 & 5 & 2 \\
4 & 1 & a^2-14 & a+2
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & -3 & 4 \\
0 & -7 & 14 & -10 \\
0 & -7 & a^2-2 & a-10
\end{array}\right]
&&\begin{aligned}R_2&\gets R_2-3R_1\\ R_3&\gets R_3-4R_1\end{aligned}
\\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & -3 & 4 \\
0 & -7 & 14 & -10 \\
0 & 0 & a^2-16 & a
\end{array}\right]
&&R_3\gets R_3-R_2
\end{align}
You can clearly see that the transformed system has a unique solution if and only if $a^2-16\ne0$.

For $a^2-16=0$, the third row has a nonzero entry in the last column, which says the system has no solution.

Answer (score 0):

As the linear system is a non-homogeneous one (why?), it has one unique solution iff the matrix of coefficients of the system is regular iff its determinant is non-zero, so:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&2&\!-3\\
3&\!-1&5\\
4&1&a^2-14\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-3R_1,\,R_4-4R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{vmatrix}
1&2&\!-3\\
0&\!-7&14\\
0&\!-7&a^2-2\end{vmatrix}=-7(a^2-2)+98=0\iff$$$${}$$

$$\iff\;\;a^2=100\iff a=\ldots$$$${}$$

So now you know when the system has one unique solution. For the two values of $\;a\;$ for which there is no *unique* solution, you have to check each one and find out whether you get infinite solutions (as I think you are working over the real numbers), or whether you get *no solution* at all...and you can use the above calculations...